# push local variables

Tags: assembly

Alo

After I have read about function and stack from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames I have a question about local variables.

Snapshot from the article:

---

```
push ebp     ; save the value of ebp
mov ebp, esp ; ebp now points to the top of the stack
sub esp, 12  ; space allocated on the stack for the local variables
```

This means local variables can be accessed by referencing ebp. Consider the following C code fragment and corresponding assembly code:

```
a = 10;
b = 5;
c = 2;

mov [ebp -  4], 10  ; location of variable a
mov [ebp -  8], 5   ; location of b
mov [ebp - 12], 2   ; location of c
```

Remember that pushing basically does this:

```
sub esp, 4   ; "allocate" space for the new stack item
mov [esp], X ; put new stack item value X in
```

---

Why are local variables not push into the stack like this:

```
push 10
push 5
push 2
```

instead of

```
sub esp, 12

mov [ebp -  4], 10  ; location of variable a
mov [ebp -  8], 5   ; location of b
mov [ebp - 12], 2   ; location of c
```

Comment: You can do on boath ways, but be carefull about pushing order!

Comment: Is sub esp,4 - mov [esp], 10 not equal to mov [ebp-4],10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more a matter of semantics rather than of technical correctness: `push` and `pop` are used to save and restore registers or values; but providing **local variables** for a function does not correspond to this regular purpose of `push`/`pop`. So, the stack is managed manually here (except of `push ebp` and `pop ebp`, because here we actually want to save and restore `ebp` in the true sense of `push`/`pop`).

Comment: Thx for the explanation. The snapshot is for local variables in a function and not parameters for a function. In the article they use push for parameters to a function so that confuse me why local variables is not push like parameters in the function

Comment: Ups, I confused. I meant local variables. Sorry. I've edited the post now.

Answer (score 3):

Practically speaking, if you know how much stack space you need and reserve it in a single operation you can then use the mov instruction which executes faster than a push immed (especially now that the offset calculation has dedicated hardware).  There's also perhaps a legacy component having to do with the fact that push immed didn't become available on the x86 until the release of the 80186/80188 processors.  By that time, the sub/mov convention had become a well established pattern.

Comment: I see. I don't think the legacy issue about push is a problem for me. But I see that the performance can have an impact using push. The push is using a [sub esp, 4] extra instruction for every local variables